# shared preference macos lib missing from Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, sharedpreferences

I have this error with my Flutter app that caused by Dart SDK

[image: macos shared preference]

I use Flutter 1.22.6 with Dart SDK 2.10.5 (stable) & intellij 2020.3 ...
when click on fix only remove shows, after remove the error goes, but then the error starts popup ...as I'm doing Android app so it's not affecting , but later for the iOS version I guess it will affect .

any idea how to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a cache problem.

Try to run the following commands:

1. `flutter pub cache repair`
2. `flutter packages get`

Comment: I tried, but didn't work...Thank you for your try.